# Why a Golang process launched by GoLand became a zombie process?

Tags: macos, goland, zombie-process

Today I encountered a weird problem there is a zombie process that is seemly launched by GoLand IDE, the full command of the process is:

```
$> ps 45040
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
45040   ??  S     23:42.94 /private/var/folders/1w/f8m7sq110sb5zlf7q5hlvn8m0000gn/T/GoLand/___debug_orders_svr
```

and it shows that its parent process is `launchd`:

```sh
$ ps -o ppid,pid 45040                                                                                                                         
 PPID   PID
    1 45040
$ ps 1                                                                                                                                         
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
    1   ??  Ss     6:03.25 /sbin/launchd
```

I tried closing my GoLand IDE, but the process is still there, I guess there was something weird that caused the zombie process.

Has someone encountered this kind of problem? And who knows what happened?

Additionally, my development environment is:

Mac OS version 10.15.7,
GoLand 2021.2,
go version go1.17.6 darwin/amd64

Comment: It looks like a process from run/debug session in GoLand. Can you reproduce it constantly? What were your previous actions in the IDE?

Comment: I faced the same issue with Goland failing to open in Mac(Intel) Monterey & Java 18, hence first download Jetbrains Toolbox, and then try to install the GoLand from there, probably it would help you, hope so!